# MySQL database in iPhone xcode

Tags: iphone, mysql, xcode, uiimage, uilabel

How can I present a UILabel and a UIImage from MySQL database? I am able to connect the app with the MySQL database but Im confused of how I can present it in a UILabel and a UIImage view.

Here is my code:

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithformat:@"http://localhost/database/login.php?username=1234];

NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access PHP script in iOS, since PHP needs a PHP server like Wamp / Apache to get PHP script executed.

For database interaction, please refer to [this link](http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/) 
Also refer to core data if you want

Comment: I am using MAMP to connect to the database and it worked perfectly, I just want to know how to present the information in my database using UIImage and UILabel...